# File Sharing API or Framework in OS X 10.5.*

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-sharing

Is there any programming interface or CLI for changing network or file sharing settings in OS X Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called dscl (Directory Service command line utility).

Comment: After doing some research on dscl, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: dscl can also be used to change a user's ID/group/etc.  Took a while to figure out how to do this, but it can be done!